# Quartz 2.0.2 - Schedule recurrent event

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I'm lost In quartz 2.0 definition. I would like to schedule `SimpleTrigger` which will

- start at  12/20/2012 until 12/31/2017
- take place every three days
- will happen at 5pm.

  ```
       Date start = 12/20/2012;
       Date endDate = 12/31/2017;
       SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
                  .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
                  .startAt(startDate) 
                  .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                  .withIntervalInHours(3 * 24)                   
                  .build();
  ```

How can I add 5pm occurrence and `endDate` parameters to `TriggerBuilder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date start = 12/20/2012;
Date endDate = 12/31/2017;
SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .startAt(startDate) 
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("* * 17 0/3 * *").build())
    .endAt(endDate)
    .build;
```

I haven't tested this myself, but this should work or might at least need some tweaks.